# How can get top of records by GreenDAO?

Tags: android, sqlite, greendao

I wanna to get top some records from my table, but GreenDAO doesn't provide it.
Like this:

> SELECT TOP 1 * FROM table_name

In LINQ you can get top of records with `Take()`, is there any solution for GreenDAO?

Could every one offer a suggestion?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

You can specify a limit using standard QueryBuilder:

```
List<YourEntity> entities = yourDao.queryBuilder().limit(1).list();
```

Comment: Unfortunately When I run it, doesn't work and show error. please write a complete example(when I want to get a row from a table)

Comment: Thanks @greenrobot, you was right. I did test it and it worked correctly.

Comment: sorry for found it too late, please expain what is "limit(1)" , many thanks

Comment: limit(n) - select top n records from table

Comment: @niveuseverto  top n records mean, first added or last added?

Comment: @Mani depends on order clause

Answer (score 0):

```
 var mcc: SearchDao
      
 val list: List<Search?> =mcc.queryBuilder().orderDesc(SearchDao.Properties.Time).limit(8).list()
```